# How to add "N" prefix to Stored Procedure parameter from c# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

C# code:

```
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("My_StoredProcedure", myConnection))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter","Quản trị");
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_StoredProcedure] 
    (@Parameter NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Things I tried:

- Changed `AddWithValue` in order to set `SqlDbType.VarChar` as below

  ```
  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Quản trị";
  ```
- Then changed stored procedure parameter type to `varchar` as below

  ```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_StoredProcedure]
      (@Parameter VARCHAR(MAX))
  ```

**Question:**

Things I tried did not work to shown correct text value. Text always appears as `Qu?n tr?` in the stored procedure side.

If I try below this works but this is not what I want. I want to add "N" prefix from code (C#) side. So I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_StoredProcedure]
    (@Parameter NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Quản trị')
```

What kind of solution should I apply in C# or SQL Server?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your code looks fine, `nvarchar` and `AddWithValue` is correct for Unicode strings (`varchar` is *not* correct). What does your SP do with the value? Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces this issue with SSMS?

Comment: Did you check this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/88c9bcdb-fc66-4a26-9d3d-692b2df41e7b/syntax-to-pass-a-parameter-of-type-nvarcharmax-to-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql Example- `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, Name.Length, Name)`

Comment: You should be passing it from C# as `nvarchar`, not `varchar`. And you shouldn't need to do anything else. The `N` prefix is a *T-SQL* language construct relating to string literals. If you're not writing a string literal in T-SQL, that language's conventions are irrelevant.

Comment: The `N` prefix for `nvarchar` strings is a proper way to use Unicode characters, but you should use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` to pass those kind of strings from C# to SQL Server parameters.

Comment: The second parameter for AddWithValue is always a value not a type. The syntax you showed in your example is for Add.

Comment: Passing data type is "Nvarchar" but i will try solution of @SouvikGhosh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would keep the data type in SQL as an `NVARCHAR` because that is what it should be and the C# code should like this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value
```

You have passed in `VarChar` instead of `NVarChar` so it makes sense for Unicode not to display.

Comment: `Add`, not `AddWithValue`. At the moment, this boxes the enum value to `object`, I'm guessing the system will work out the underlying type of the enum and most likely creates the parameter to have a data type of `int`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Flew past me. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I tried 
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Quản trị"; and did not work for me.

Comment: Where is "Quản trị" coming from? A TextBox?

Comment: @SonerSevinc - then this all looks right from the C# side, time to see if the stored proc is misbehaving.